# MySQLDump backup a MySQL containing table of different charset

Tags: mysql

If a database contains contains table of different charset, what should I do in order to have them appear in a single file? or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be better off using the `--tab` option to mysqldump and dumping each table to a separate `.sql` and `.txt` pair of files, but if you want to use a single dump file I'd:

- Use mysqldump as usual specifying the default charset of the majority of the tables.
- Then edit the dump file to change the charset in the creation statement for the tables that are different.

If the dump's huge use an editor that can handle such files or make the changes using `sed`.

A third alternative would be to use just two dump files by selecting tables using the `--tables` parameter to mysqldump. First select all the regular tables and then select the group that's different, specifying the right charset as default each time.